# Timer triggered Azure Function app fails sometimes and runs at a different time slot

Tags: azure-functions, azure-function-app, azure-functions-runtime

So I've created a Azure Function and deployed it under Consumption Plan, it is supposed to trigger every hour, but the problem here is that it sometimes does not trigger at the specified time, and there's a delayed trigger, the delayed trigger varies between 30 mins to sometimes a couple of hours, i'm not sure what should be done here

This is my CRON

```
0 */1 * * *
```

I deployed it using the profile in VS2019
I've also configured the TimeZone for this as Pacific Time and the time reflects onto the app as well
I got to know about this when I checked the monitor section
This is what I got as when it skipped and ran after a little while

> 2020-11-26 09:53:30.106
> Trigger Details: UnscheduledInvocationReason: IsPastDue, OriginalSchedule: 2020-11-26T01:00:00.0000000-08:00
> Information
> 2020-11-26 09:53:30.125
> Today's DateTime is 11/26/2020 1:53:30 AM
> Information

Any Inputs would be really helpful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-timer?tabs=csharp#ncrontab-expressions), the right CRON expression to use is `0 0 * * * *`

Comment: its not necessary but weirdly enough it seems to work if its a 6 parameter CRON